# Not clear from where application is take in the Docker image

Tags: docker

Below is the simple Docker image

- docker pull kodekloud/click-counter
- https://hub.docker.com/r/kodekloud/click-counter

I don't understand from where we take app.py in the image above, that after is run by Flask:

- https://hub.docker.com/layers/kodekloud/click-counter/latest/images/sha256-530e4532a718e8f5cbda05844a6c0638ebe8898fa4c4307ee6afbdd5d1f213db?context=explore

Could you please clarify this question for me?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it's getting copied during the build from a local directory probably by command 19 or 22